# Iterate array object using foreach in javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach

Below is an array of objects which I need to print in the below expected format only using `forEach` in javascript

```
var donuts = [
    { type: "Dairy Milk", cost: 1.22 },//object
    { type: "Kit Kat", cost: 2.45 },
    { type: "Milky Bar", cost: 1.59 }
];
```

Expected output:

```
Dairy Milk cost $1.22 each
Kit Kat cost $2.45 each
Milky Bar cost $1.59 each
```

How do I do that?

Comment: please also show us what you have already tried

Comment: Is it too difficult to http://google.it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
donuts.forEach(d => console.log(`${d.type} cost $${d.cost} each`))
```

Every array in JavaScript has a method called `forEach` that basically calls a function for each of the elements of your array. Inside this function you can call `console.log`.

The example above uses the arrow function notation, which apart from a few differences is basically just a more concise way to declare a function.

Also in this example you can notice the use of string templates, denoted by the text inside backticks, where you can use placehoders `${}` to place dynamic content in your string.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: You are totally right @MaximilianPeters I have actually answered this question on the mobile app and will improve the answer as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
yourArray.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element.type + ‘ costs $’ + element.cost + ‘ each’);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Herman and Renato